# How to retrieve value from dictionary with dynamic key in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I need to fetch and display the the value from dictionary using dynamic key in Django template.

**Model**:

```
class StatusData(models.Model):
   app= models.CharField(max_length=35)
   status= models.CharField(max_length=3) //possible values - SNY,DVL,TST

    class Meta:
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status
```

**view.py**

```
all_choices = {'SNY':'Sanity', 'DVL':'Develop', 'TST':'Testing'}
model = StatusData.objects.order_by('-app') 

context = {
   "choices": all_choices,
   "modelData": model,
}
```

**Django template**:

```
<html>
   {% for model%}
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ model.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ choices.model.status }}</td>  // -- problem line
     </tr>
   </table>
   {% endfor %}
</html>
```

If I hardcode any specific key like `{{ choices.SNY }}` - it's deriving the the value as expected.

How can I fetch the value by using the dynamic key that is returned by `model.status` i.e., `{{ choices.<model.status> }}`?

Comment: `{{ choices.model.status }}` doesn't make a lot of sense to me. In your `view.py`, `choices` contains a hard-coded dictionary, but the `choices` in Django seems to be of a different type entirely.

Comment: @timthefiend I added harcoded values just for reference. In our project we'll get them from data base lookups. I just need a way to pass key dynamically just like we do in other programming languages (e.g., Map.get(key) in java)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply use use Pythonic logic inside templates. It's not that simple to get from dict using variable. You can try creating a custom template tags.

Create file in your app: "`your_project/your_app/templatetags/custom_tags.py`" (and empty "`__init__.py`" in the same folder):

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

all_choices = {'SNY':'Sanity', 'DVL':'Develop', 'TST':'Testing'}

@register.filter(name='get_from_all_choices') 
def get_from_all_choices (key):
    return all_choices.get(key, None)
```

And then in template:

```html
{% load custom_tags %}

{{ model.status|get_from_all_choices }}
```